# How to close the Modal using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a dropdown list, when I click on any of the dropdown value then a modal get opens, When I click outside the modal, it will get close. How to handle it with Selenium WebDriver?

here is my Modal Code

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
     <div class="modal-content">You click on Dropdown hover Option
     </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried with below code

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

and

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

But both are not working.

Comment: try `driver.switchTo().activeElement()` not sure, but try and let us know

Comment: This isn't a JavaScript Alert so you don't need to use the switchTo() functionality.  Just click on another element to dismiss it.

Comment: Try sending `ESC` key command using the actions API. It will escape the modal and it will be closed.

Comment: Doesn't the _Modal Dialog_ fade away automatically after certain time interval? Is clicking outside the modal necessary?

Comment: @Ardesco, I have tried to click on the other elements from the POM, but getting org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException

Comment: @demouser123, I have tried this method, and it works, But I want to handle it by another method

Comment: It's a normal user behavior to dismiss such a modal via `ESC`. Why do you want to handle it other way if there is a solution available?

Comment: You haven't provided enough markup for an accurate answer.  Normally controls like this have a display box layered on top of an opaque element that covers the entire page.  It's the opaque element rather than the display box showing some information that you would expect to click on.

Comment: @Ardesco I was going through the site "https://demo.stqatools.com/MouseHover.php", you can try it, On mouse hovers on the "Mouse Hover DropDown" button, a dropdown list will display. On click of the dropdown list, you will see the above mentioned modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to hit the Esc key you can click on div that has been created to cover the rest of the page using the following:

```
    driver.get("https://demo.stqatools.com/MouseHover.php");
    WebElement hoverButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".dropbtn"));
    WebElement linkOne = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".dropdown-content > a"));

    //Activate modal dialogue
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(hoverButton).perform();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(linkOne));
    action.moveToElement(linkOne).click().perform();

    //Dismiss modal dialogue
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".show")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way - it's click on some static text on page. 
Try click on page title (if exist).

Comment: Click on _Page Title_? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, or any another element on page.
Clicking on static text the most safe action, because test not affect and not change system.

Comment: Code sample for clicking on _Page Title_?

Comment: For example: DOM has //h2[.='Personal Information']
page screen https://prnt.sc/o5zmkv

Sample? Just usual Selenium click, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert), it's just a normal piece of [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_htmldom.asp) which looks like a modal popup due to [CSS styling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)

So all you need to do is to locate the element using, for instance it's text, the relevant [XPath locator](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) would be something like:

```
//div[contains(text(),'You click on Dropdown hover Option')]
```

It would be also good to "wait" until popup presence/intractability via [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) like:

```
new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        .until(
                ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
                        By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'You click on Dropdown hover Option')]")))
        .click();
```